# javascript onchage select and update an input or text object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I want to make a selection (without a php or other code) and when the value changes, I want to put the value in another html tag like an Input field. I've looked upon w3 schools and there's only code for getting the value of the select tag. Here's what I've tried:

```
<body>

         <select name="selection" id="selection" onchange="update(this.value)">
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>

          </select>

<input name="desc" type="text" id="desc" />

</body>
<script>
function update(val) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("desc");
    x.value = val;
    $('desc').val(val);
 }
 </script>
```

So, in the input text should update with the value from the select? Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think you are overthinking it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>

         <select name="selection" id="selection" onchange="update(this.value)">
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>

          </select>

<input name="desc" type="text" id="desc" />

</body>
<script>
function update(val) {
    $('#desc').val(val);
 }
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

         <select name="selection" id="selection" onchange="update(this.value)">
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>

          </select>

<input name="desc" type="text" id="desc" />

</body>
<script>
function update(val) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("desc");
    x[0].value = val;
    $('desc').val(val);
 }
 </script>
```

**document.getElementsByName** return array, you have to provide index for x to provide value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <script>
 function update(combo) {
    var x = document.getElementById("desc");
    x.value = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
 }    
  </script>
  <!--js-->
</head>

<body>
<select name="selection" id="selection" onchange="update(this)">
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>

          </select>

<input name="desc" type="text" id="desc" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use proper very less jQuery Code

```
   <select name="selection" id="selection" >
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>
          </select>
<input name="desc" type="text" id="desc" />

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#selection").change(function(){  
        $('#desc').val(this.value);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two changes to your script.

A) Remove `$('desc').val(val)` line. It is not needed since `x.value = val` would suffice.

B) You can change `var x = document.getElementsByName("desc")` into `var x = document.getElementById("desc")`. Since you have name and id same, we can use getElementById() in place of current one. As getElementsByName() returns an array.

So the code will look like.

```
<select name="selection" id="selection" onchange="update(this.value)">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input name="desc" type="text" id="desc" />

<script>
function update(val) {
    var x = document.getElementById("desc");
    x.value = val;
}
</script>
```

Also, since you are calling your javascript method through onchange event, your solution will not work if select element has only 1 option. To fix this, try using onblur or onclick inplace of onchange depending upon your usecase.